# Which boss in Dark Souls can be buffed by a Channeler?

Tags: dark-souls

**TV TROPES LINK**

An excerpt from [this TV Tropes pages](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/DemonicSpiders/DarkSouls) says

> If you take the shortcut through the Depths and go straight for the boss, 
>       bypassing the Channeler you would have encountered on the normal route, 
>       guess what? The Channeler can buff the boss. Although many players 
>       consider that particular boss a bit too easy, so maybe you would prefer 
>       fighting it this way.

Which boss is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the [Gaping Dragon](https://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Gaping+Dragon)

> Remember to take out the Channeler before you fight this boss. There is a Channeler located near a group of large rats near the top of the wall overlooking the eventual boss fight area, beyond a small fog gate. If he is not killed prior to the fight with Gaping Dragon, the Channeler will continuously fire soul arrows at you, and may also buff the Gaping Dragon if it gets close enough to him, making it significantly stronger.

Additionally, not only does keeping the Channeler alive allow him to buff the boss, but also allows him to fire spells down at you from above.

> The Channeler's combat spells are not particularly dangerous by themselves, but have a frustrating tendency to hit you in the head from above and stagger you just as you are attempting to either run at or roll away from the boss.

Fortunately this enemy does not respawn once killed, so you won't have to deal with him every time, if you die to the boss.

Comment: TIL - beat this game 100 times and I never knew that

Comment: Honestly a normal player isn't going to leave a ranged spellcaster alive anyways, so typically that's not a normal way to play.  However, if you were speed running, you'll probably explicitly target him to increase your survival rates.

Comment: @Nelson I'd expect speedrunners to skip the boss entirely and use the master key to get to blighttown.

Comment: @JAD my first play through I didn't even know about the Depths or that boss. I went into Blight Town through the Valley and had no clue that it wasn't considered the "normal" way.

Comment: @Logarr it's by far the easier road of the two towards Quelaag.